# How do USB to DVI adapters plug into monitors? (Cord and port are both female.)

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, dvi, external-display, adapter

I feel like this must be so simple that I will be shunned from the site in contempt, but how does a USB-to-DVI adapter connect to a monitor when its male end is USB (plugs into computer) and its female end is DVI (somehow connects to monitor)?

Every monitor I've seen has a female port, and as far as I know, lesbian relationships aren't allowed between cord and port.

[All these adapters clearly have female DVI ends.](https://www.google.com/#q=usb+to+dvi+adapter&tbm=shop)

No one in the numerous reviews for these products seems to mention using an *additional* adapter to convert female to male, if that were even an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally they're adapters, not all-in-one cables.  You plug a standard dvi cable from the adapter into your monitor.  Most modern monitors come with such a cable.  Otherwise, you will have to pick one up.
Remember, they're -adapters-, not -cables-.  Generally expect to use an additional cable with an 'adapter' of any sort.  Something to watch for.

Comment: There's that obvious answer I was missing. I expected everything needed to come with the adapter (because a USB to HDMI cord did come with it) and didn't think it through. Thanks.

Comment: No problem- they don't like advertising that you may need something else.  It's been more than once that I've been burned ;)

Answer (score 2):

Those adapters are not made to plug directly into a display.

Most *devices* (input or output) will have a female port, and thus the cables are typically male-to-male.